# `pip install` a custom python package from within a python:3.6.8 container fails (but works outside the container)

Tags: python, docker, pip, setuptools

I am trying to build a container using the docker official `python:3.6.8` image that will encapsulate a python package I am developing along with its dependencies. The idea is to supply the container with the code repository using the `ADD mypkg.tar.gz /pytmp/mypkg` directive then create a virtualenv and install `mypkg` from within this env, then output the corresponding `site-packages` directory to share it later.

My Dockerfile first gets `virtualenv` through `apt-get` then creates the dummy environment and tries to install the package before zipping `site-packages`:

```
RUN cd /pytmp && \
    virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 venv && \
    source venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install -v mypkg
RUN cd /pytmp/venv/lib/python3.6/ && \
    zip -r /python_packages.zip site-packages/
```

Under my system (ubuntu 18.04), I can do a working `pip install .` from `mypkg` root directory. But inside the container, the install fails with error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypkg (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypkg

Is pip looking for mypkg on pypi ? Is there something wrong with my instructions ?

I am using a `setup.cfg`-only scheme. The `setup.cfg` contains the following

```
[options]
packages = find_namespace:
package_dir =
    =src
install_requires=
    numpy
    pyspark
    sklearn
    pylint
    pre-commit

[options.extras_require]
test = pytest
docs = Sphinx; sphinx-rtd-theme

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: use `WORKDIR` instead of `RUN cd`
```
WORKDIR pytmp 
RUN virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 venv && \
    source venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install -v mypkg

WORKDIR  /pytmp/venv/lib/python3.6 
RUN  zip -r /python_packages.zip site-packages/
```
Do you have `site-packag`? if it does not exist, it will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably failing because you're pointing it at a thing that looks like a package name, rather than like a directory. Make sure you're doing `pip install /actual/path/to/your/package`, with a slash at end at least, might need full path, as right now it's going to try to install from PyPI.

However: you really shouldn't be distributing `site-packages`. For libraries, just distribute your tarball. If you're distributing an application, the full Docker image might work, or you can use PyInstaller, or other tools (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/distributing-software/ has a survey).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the directory vs package name issue, that was indeed the reason it failed !

I suspected that distributing `site-packages` was definitely not the way to go, but unfortunately, I have pretty much no other permission than to copy some files on the remote machine where I will import libs and execute some code. Am I right to think that the solutions proposed in this survey require more than just using `sys` and `import` ?